# Scala Type Mismatch in FoldLeft operation

Tags: scala, fold

I'm very new to Scala so excuse that this is probably a simple misunderstanding of the language. I have a function:

```
def compareNextElemToMinElem(lst: List[Int]) = {
    val max = lst.foldLeft((lst(0),lst(0),0)) { (minSoFar:Int, x:Int, maxDiff:Int) => 
        if (x < minSoFar) (minSoFar, x, maxDiff) 
        if (x - minSoFar > maxDiff) (minSoFar, x, x - minSoFar)
        else (minSoFar, x, x - minSoFar)
    }
    max._3
}
```

Basically it *should* go one element at a time and track the biggest difference in elements so far. By calling `max._3` I hope to return the final `maxDiff` from the foldLeft call. I'm getting an error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int, Int) => (Int, Int, Int)
 required: ((Int, Int, Int), Int) => (Int, Int, Int)
    val max = lst.foldLeft((lst(0),lst(0),0)) { (minSoFar:Int, x:Int, maxDiff:Int) =>
```

Additionally, I have to put `(minSoFar:Int, x:Int, maxDiff:Int)` instead of `(minSoFar, x, maxDiff)` to avoid a `missing parameter type` error. Why is that?

Comment: "biggest difference in elements" - in *what* elements? What is it supposed to compute? `lst.max - lst.min`? Or maximum difference between two consecutive elements? In any case, the fold does not expect a three-argument function, you have to nest the tuples differently, and you probably need a `case` to match all the components properly.

Comment: not `lst.max - lst.min` but rather the current element minus the min so far. I'm not sure what you mean, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: for list(1,2,3,-1,4,-2) I'd want 4-(-1) or 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the syntax and logic seemed not entirely correct, here is a possible fix:

```
def compareNextElemToMinElem(lst: List[Int]) = {
  lst.foldLeft((lst.head, lst.head)) { case ((minSoFar, maxDiff), x) =>
    if (x < minSoFar) (x, maxDiff) 
    else if (x - minSoFar > maxDiff) (minSoFar, x - minSoFar)
    else (minSoFar, maxDiff)
  }._2
}

println(compareNextElemToMinElem(List(1,-2,3,-1,4,8,2)))
```

prints

```
10
```

which is `8 - (-2)`.

Brief explanation:

1. You want to keep track of two values: `minSoFar` and `maxDiff`, not three.
2. You have to look at the content of the list: `x` must come from the list,
   not from the "accumulator" that is passed from previous step
3. `fold`, in general, takes a function that takes two arguments:

   ```
   list.fold(accumulator0){ (acc, currentValue) => nextAcc }
   ```
4. Since here your accumulator `acc` is itself a tuple, you have to pattern match on the first component with `case`, so:

   ```
   list.fold((a0, b0)) { case ((ai, bi), x) => (nextAi, nextBi) }
   ```
5. I didn't understand your `if-else` logic, no guarantee that it does what you intended.

Comment: Gotcha this makes sense. Why do we need `case ((minSoFar, maxDiff), x)` if we're not in a match statement?

Comment: @FranklinHarvey As I said, it's for decomposing the `acc` tuple into `(minSoFar, maxDiff)`. Search for "scala pattern matching case functions" (searching better link).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass minSofar and maxDiff as Tuple2 or pair.So It should be like below code :

```
def compareNextElemToMinElem(lst: List[Int]) = {
    val max = lst.foldLeft((lst(0),0)) { (p : Tuple2[Int,Int], x:Int) =>
      var minSoFar = p._1;
      var maxDiff = p._2
      if (x < minSoFar) {
        maxDiff = maxDiff + minSoFar - x
        minSoFar = x
      }
      if (x - minSoFar > maxDiff){
        maxDiff = x - minSoFar
      }
      (minSoFar,maxDiff)
    }
    max._2
  }
```

follow this [link](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-foldleft-example/) to know more about foldleft arguments .

Comment: What exactly does it do? Because of the strange `maxDiff + x - minSoFar`, I thought that it would output `6` on the given example, but even more surprisingly, `compareNextElemToMinElem(List(1,2,3,-1,4,-2))` gives `4` instead of `5`?

Comment: It should be  maxDiff = maxDiff - ( x - minSoFar)